# Can't Get moveToElement To Display Tooltip For SVG element On Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, svg, selenium-webdriver

I've been working on this test script and I can't get it to mouse over an element in the SVG to show the tool tip.

I've stored it in a variable and able to output an attribute using the xpath but when I call it using moveToElement it doesn't work.

This is the xpath I am using:

```
//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][@class='highcharts-series-group']/*[name()='g'][18]/*[name()='path'][2]
```

but this xpath works:

```
//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][@class='highcharts-series-group']/*[name()='g'][18]/*[name()='path'][1]
```

I've also tried [stats-with ., val] with no success.

Update:
Adding html of the elements

```
<g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="12" transform="translate(0,26) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-438)" style="">
    <path fill="#bdc94b" d="M 440 295.19999990878046 C 445.328 295.19999990878046 445.328 303.19999990878046 440 303.19999990878046 C 434.672 303.19999990878046 434.672 295.19999990878046 440 295.19999990878046 Z"></path>
    <path fill="#bdc94b" d="M 417 292.4634146341463 C 422.328 292.4634146341463 422.328 300.4634146341463 417 300.4634146341463 C 411.672 300.4634146341463 411.672 292.4634146341463 417 292.4634146341463 Z"></path></g>
```

Update:

So after using .click().build().perform(); I am now getting a element not clickable error message.  It turns out there is another element overlaying the plot in a later  tag.  What would be a good work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

The first (failing) xpath is looking for the second <path> element, whereas your second (working) xpath  is getting the first path element.  Seems to me the the source file only has one <path> element in the 18th group.

Btw, the xpath could be simplified so that is is easier to read , and more efficient.

```
//svg/g[@class='highcharts-series-group']/g[18]/path[1]
```

since  /*[name()='{nodename}']  is equivalent to   /{nodename}

Comment: Thanks for the response and tip!  So I know that theres a 2nd <path> in the 18th group since when I run the test it doesn't fail.  My trouble is that when I use that xpath to mouse/hover over using actions.moveToElement(element); it doesn't show/find it to show the tooltip.

Comment: Hmmm... in that case, Do you have another object that is above the element? It may have priority over the mouse event.  I think even transparent elements (unless clipped) will also have priority if above another.

Comment: Possibly.  It just doesn't make sense to me that the 1st path works but the 2nd doesn't even though they're part of the same 18th <g>.  As far as other objects above the element, I don't see one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant think of anything else.. Can you copy the svg element into an .svg file and then load it into a tool such as InkSpace.  If the region is truely unreachable by the mouse, then it'll be repeatable in the tool and/or you may get some insight into the cause.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll try that.